# How to retrieve page with special characters in page name

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Trying to retrieve general page info using the Facebook graph API using an Jquery/Ajax call. This works flawlessly until I request a page containing special characters or dashes in it's name.

It seems like the special characters are ANSI encoded during the ajax request so the name is malformed and the page cannot be found. I can't find a way though to obviate this.

Example url: https://graph.facebook.com/Musée-de-la-Photographie-Charleroi?access_token=[my_access_token]

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should test different values in contentType parameter. It allows to set char encoding.
Take a look here:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

> It seems like the special characters are ANSI encoded during the ajax request so the name is malformed and the page cannot be found.

No, I don’t think that’s the problem.

As you can see from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=18521449287, this page does not have a *username* set yet – and since it is not accessible via just `www.facebook.com/Musée-de-la-Photographie-Charleroi`, but only via `www.facebook.com/pages/Musée-de-la-Photographie-Charleroi/18521449287` including the page id.

And accordingly, info about the page on the Graph API is only available via the page id as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the page_id instead (in this case 131141113604635).

```
https://graph.facebook.com/131141113604635?access_token=[my_access_token]
```

You may get this id by opening the page on the browser and pressing Ctrl+U, Ctrl+F and searching for a 'page_id' value.

Comment: You may also search for a 'group_id' value instead if the feed in question belongs to a group rather than a page.